# Como capturar o valor de uma chave de um JSON (proveniente de um AJAX) usando Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte AJAX:

```
$("button[name='btn-editar-marca']").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../ajax/ajax.marcas.php",
        data: {"ajax-params": 2, "Id_Marca": $(this).attr("id")},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
            $("input[name='inputCodMarca']").val(res.Id_Marca);
            $("input[name='inputNomeMarca']").val(res.Nome_Marca);
            $("input[name='textareaObsMarca']").val(res.Obs_Marca);
            $("input[name='inputDataCadMarca']").val(res.Data_Cadastro);
            $('#md-editar-marca').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(res){
            if(res.status == 200)
                alert("Erro 200");
            else if(res.status == 404)
                alert("Erro 404");
            else
                alert("Algo de errado não está certo!");
        }
    });
});
```

O `console.log(res)` no meio mostra o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abri-lo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir a "posição [0]":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esses valores que apareceram na posição 0 são os que eu desejo capturar para inseri-los em `inputs`, eu até consigo pega-los assim:

```
res[0].Id_Marca
res[0].Nome_Marca
```

Essa é a única maneira de capturar os valores? Eu gostaria de algo mais "profissional", assim por dizer, alguma função, algo assim, pois, nesse caso, é um select que traz apenas 1 valor (selectPorId), logo, só terá a posição 0 mesmo, mas logo menos eu terei que trazer mais valores, por exemplo: "Selecionar os itens de uma compra". Muitas vezes vai ter mais de 1 item, logo, teria que ser algo dinamico. Como eu poderia substituir esse `res[0].VALORES` por algo dinamico?

Vi a função `JSON.parse()` mas não deu certo, talvez por eu não saber usa-lá ou talvez não ser a função ideal pro caso.

Comment: É assim mesmo. Utilizar `[0]` não tem nada de errado. O mais certo, na verdade, seria retornar os dados em formato de objeto (e não de array), através do back-end. Aí sim, você poderia fazer `res.Id_Marca`.

Comment: Você pode dar um `res = res[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso de seu array tiver mais de 1 elemento você vai ter de usar a função .map() ou mesmo um for pra percorrer o seu array:

```
res.map((i, j) => {
  console.log(res[j].Id_Marca)
  console.log(res[j].Nome_Marca)
});
```

Assim você não precisará se preocupar com o tamanho do retorno do seu json.